# How to send XML from Ajax to Spring Conroller

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send xml data from jquery ajax to spring controller and trying to parse the xml in java. However unable to proceed further.

Could you please help me to solve this problem -

Here is what I am trying -

Sample XMl -

```
<Company>
<Employees>
 <Employee>
 <ID>1</ID>
<Name>
 <fname>
      Anand
 </fname>
 <lname>
     Chavan
 </lname>
 </Name>
</Employee>

 <Employee>
 <ID>2</ID>
<Name>
 <fname>
      Rahul
 </fname>
 <lname>
     Dravid
 </lname>
</Name>
</Employee>
</Employees>
</Company>
```

If your observation is that the below code is missing in xml string -
(please note, I have tried both.. with and without below node)

```
<?xml version=\""+"1.0"+"\" ?>
```

Sample Ajax request -

```
function saveAjaxCall(xml){

        xml=$(xml).html();

        $.ajax({            
            url      : "bulkAdd.ext",
            type     : "POST",
            processData: false,
            dataType : "text/xml",
            data: 'data=' + xml,            
            success  : function(response){
               alert('Success');
            },
            error    : function(response) {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });

    }
```

Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bulkAdd.ext", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addBulkEmp( @RequestBody String xml) throws Exception {

    new EmpXMLParser().parseXML(xml); 
      // parser is not complete, initially just trying to count number of nodes     

    return "";          
}
```

Sample parser code -

```
public void parseXML(String xml) {

        try {

            System.out.println(xml);

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Charset.forName("UTF-8")
                    .encode(xml).array());
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db;

            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document dom = db.parse(is);
            Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();

            if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {

                System.out.println("number of Emp = " + nl.getLength());
            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException saxe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            saxe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error I am getting -

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at com.testcode.myapp.utils.EmployeeXMLParser.parseXML(EmployeeXMLParser.java:33)
    at com.testcode.myapp.controller.EmployeeController.addEmployee(EmployeeController.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:874)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:790)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Observation -

data is received by controller in below format-

```
data=%3Cemployees%3E%3Cemployee%3E%3Cid%3E1%3C%2Fid%3E%3Cname%3E%3Cfname%3EAnand%3C%2Ffname%3E%3Clname%3EChavan%3C%2Flname%3E%3C%2Fname%3E%3C%2Femployee%3E%3Cemployees%3E%3Cemployee%3E%3Cid%3E2%3C%2Fid%3E%3Cname%3E%3Cfname%3ERahul%3C%2Ffname%3E%3Clname%3EDravid%3C%2Flname%3E%3C%2Fname%3E%3C%2Femployee%3E%3C%2Femployees%3E%3C%2Femployees%3E
```

Wait -- if you feel data= is problem while passing the data -
I have tried below ways too

```
data: {data : xml }
```

or

```
data:xml,
```

Still this fails.

Master minds please raise your helping hands.

Comment: Can you post the Spring MVC controller code that you are using.

Comment: ams, please read the question again. I have added the controller sample as well.

Comment: Try to change @RequestBody for @RequestParam("data"), because you are sending something like "tag=some XML" but your code at this moment is @RequestBody="tag=some XML"

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem a few days ago. UTF-8 uses special symbols BEFORE content while XmlReader doesn't expect any data  before first line of XML.

So to deal with it you should process your String using this method:

```
public static final String UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF";

private static String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
    if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Could you try to add standard xml header to your xml text? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>